# How to add an item into Google Cloud Tasks queue in Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tools

Could anybody give me a hint how to add an item into Google Cloud Tasks queue in Java?
https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/

Google has a very smooth description of their queues v1 https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/taskqueue/pull/creating-tasks but nothing similar for a new beta Google Cloud Tasks.

I need simply to add an item into a queue with a specific tag and after to pull it from the queue by the `oldest_tag()` function.

Does anybody has an experience with Google Cloud Tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The v1 documentation page you references is specific for [pull queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/taskqueue/pull/), which aren't (yet at least) supported by Cloud Tasks.

From [The App Engine SDK versus the Cloud Tasks API](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/appengine-v-cloudtasksapi) (emphasis mine):

> Some features are not yet available via the Cloud Tasks API:
>
> - [**Pull queues**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/pull/)
> - [Adding tasks asynchronously](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-tasks#adding_tasks_asynchronously)
> - [Transactional tasks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-tasks#enqueuing_tasks_in_cloud_datastore_transactions)
> - [Deferred tasks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-tasks#using_the_deferred_instead_of_a_worker_service)
> - [Namespacing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-tasks#working_with_tasks_in_a_multi-tenant_application)
> - [Local emulator](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server)

Comment: excuse me, do you mean that now we're not able to use Cloud Tasks as a queue?

Comment: As a [push queue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/taskqueue/push/) yes, as a pull queue no.

Comment: @DanCornilescu Do I understand this correctly, that Pull Queues will be retired in February and Google has no replacement product yet? Google's documentation is in indeed very vague. Do you know by chance what devs are supposed to do if they actually need pull queues?

Comment: Where do you see that Pull Queues will be retired in February?

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate ways to access the Task service:

- Using the App Engine SDK (App Engine standard first generation runtimes)
- Using the Cloud Tasks API which is in beta (every body else, particularly second generation runtimes like Python 3.7 or App Engine flex).  There are REST or gRPC- based APIs available.  Currently the Cloud Tasks API supports only push-type queues.  The Cloud Pub/Sub API can be used for many pull queue type use cases.